# Cocos2d - last scene not loading - Child already added. It can't be added again

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my game, the scene before the final scene, it crashes when I clicked the next button with the message;

"child already added. It can't be added again"

This is the code segment of the scene, the final scene I am trying to call is called `LastScene`, however it crashes before it loads that scene.

```
bool LipsColorScene::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCPoint location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(pTouch->getLocationInView());

    if(_next->isVisible())
      {

    if(flagnext)
    {
    if(_next->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
    {

        LipsColorScene::flagnext=false;
        CCLog("click next");
        _next->setVisible(false);
        _next->setPosition(ccp(1500, -500));
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
        imageForShowingMask->setVisible(false);
      //  this->setScale(1.0f);
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
        LipsColorScene::screenshot= this;
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->removeChild(screenshot);
        lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
               imageForShowingMask->setVisible(false);
             //  this->setScale(1.0f);
               lipstickscrollview->setVisible(false);
      //  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sounds/btn_clicksound.mp3");
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(LastScene::scene());
    }
    }
      }
    if(imageForShowingMask->isVisible())
    {

        if(imageForShowingMask->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
        {
            CCLOG("touch began");
            imageForShowingMask->setTag(1);
            setMaskingParamsForCream();
            //sprayparticle->resetSystem();
            spongeSelected = true;

            _eyes2->setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    if(_table->boundingBox().containsPoint(location)  && lipstickscrollview->isVisible())
    {
        if (lipstickscrollview->isVisible() && lipstickscrollview->isVisible() ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lipstickArr->count(); i++) {
                CCSprite* tatoo = (CCSprite*)lipstickArr->objectAtIndex(i);

                if(tatoo->boundingBox().containsPoint(tatoo->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(location)))
                {
                    //tatooscrollview->setVisible(false);
                    imageForShowingMask->setVisible(true);
                    LipStick(tatoo->getTag());

                }
            }
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if "CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(LastScene::scene());" is called inside your code. There can't be any reason for crashing in  your current Scene.

check in your "LastScene".